# How to remove the response body of an operation in Springfox Swagger?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, swagger-2.0, openapi, springfox

I'm working in a REST service made with spring-boot, which to this day is documented using springfox-swagger2:2.7.0 (implementation first). The last operation I've added looks like this:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "whatever")
  @ApiResponses({
    @ApiResponse(code = HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NO_CONTENT, message = "Returns empty content when succeeds"),
    @ApiResponse(code = HttpURLConnection.HTTP_FORBIDDEN, message = "You can't do that.")
  })
@CrossOrigin
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('USER_ACCESS')")
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = POST, consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
public ResponseEntity postFoo(
  @RequestBody
  FooRequestBody requestBody) {

  if (someMethodReturnsTrue()) {
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT).build();
  } else {
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
  }
}
```

Now, the problem is that no matter what, the generated Swagger definition ends up looking like this:

```
"responses": {
  "204": {
    "description": "Returns empty content when succeeds",
    "schema": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/ResponseEntity"
    }
  },
  "403": {
    "description": "You can't do that."
  }
}
```

Provided that this operation returns nothing, I understand that the "204" response should have no `schema` field (like the other one).

I've tried specifying `response = Void.class` in the `@ApiParam` annotation (as suggested in other threads) with no joy (since it is the default value it is indistinguishable from not specifying it).

I've also tried setting `genericModelSubstitutes(ResponseEntity.class)` in my `Docket` bean and that did nothing.

I know that instead of returning `ResponseEntity` I could return `void` and throw and exception in case `someMethodReturnsTrue()` returns indeed `false`. An `@ExceptionHandler` method could then turn that exception into a 403 status code.

I think this is overkill, I think I shouldn't be changing my implementation to fix my documentation. That's why I ask, is there any way to tell Springfox to ignore the return value of that specific method and treat it as if it returned `void`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add:

```
@ApiResponse(code = 204, response = void.class, message = "No Content")
```

to your `@ApiResponses({ ... })` annotation. Important is that `void.class` is used instead of `Void.class`. So it is different from the default value and you still can use `ResponseEntity` as a return type.

Comment: This does not work. Still shows the ResponseEntity body. You have to actually make the resource method return type "void" to remove the response body from the docs. Unfortunately, I can't find a way to have a ResponseEntity (with headers only for example), which shows as no body in the documentation. :/

Comment: Hi, I actually found a solution for returning a ResponseEntity in the resource method, while having it show a void body in the documentation: https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1884

Answer (score 5):

Found the workaround,
As the default behavior of @ApiOperation is to return the return type of method, so for every status, the return type of method will be returned.
If you want to send empty response then write

```
@ApiResponse(code = 204, message = "No User found for that Id",response = Object.class)
```

And in the SwaggerConfig write

```
 @Bean
    public Docket productApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
                .directModelSubstitute(Object.class, java.lang.Void.class);          
    }
```

So whenever an Object.class  is returned swagger will automatically convert it into Void.class